# Combining like items in a List

Tags: java, algorithm, list, data-structures

I saw an **[earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370294/how-to-merge-similiar-items-in-a-list)** which is trying to do a similar sort of thing in Python.

Here is a boiled down example of what I want.  Let us say I have List.

```
public class MyObject {
    private String purchase;
    private Double price;
}
```

Let us say that a typical `List<MyObject>` will hold:

```
Bike 95.00
Clothes 24.99
Clothes 10.76
Food 6.35
Food 91.46
```

I want all of the items with same purchase value to be combined into a single item with the price summed for that item.  For example, clothes would be a single item with price 35.75 (if I have done the addition correctly).

The way I thought about doing it was:

1. `Collections.sort` the list by purchase for O(n log n)
2. Walk the sorted list (it is an `ArrayList` I am using) as same items will be consecutive and perform a merge on 2 items at a time O(n)

Giving a total runtime of O(n log n).

Now that sounds reasonable to me, however is there a library out there which at the very least beats the pants of my constants?  I always support going with a streamlined version if one exists.  So are there any existing implementations that I should think about using or improvements over my algorithm?

**EDIT**

After thinking about my boiled down case as I went home yesterday, yes I easily saw it is a map.  All I had to do is reduce it to the simpler problem I posted and it became very obvious.  My real structure is

```
public class MyObject {
   Map bucketOfStuff;
}
```

In reality, bucketOfStuff is really `Map<String, Object>` where sometimes the value is a String and sometimes the value is a Double (it can also be an Integer sometimes, but hey I can treat it as double).  For all of the objects which are of type String, they would be used to form the key in this problem.  So If I had

- color => Red
- size => Small
- texture => Smooth

Then I could encode all into a single String such as `Red,Small,Smooth` because I know comma will not be a character present in any of the values so I can use it as a delimiter.

For the value for our hypothetical new Map, it would be List because I have to perform (mathematical) vector addition on all of the `bucketOfStuff` values which are doubles.  So the proposed new Map would either be `Map<List<String>, List<Double>>` or simply `Map<String, List<Double>>` if I used the delimiter as above.

Another thing which corrupted my thought process is that in the end the collection has to be a List to pass on so I was in a narrow-minded way thinking List all the way. So I have to be able to reconstruct the original object which is a bit involved, but not impossible.  Thanks all for the help and nice catch.

**EDIT**

I have to modify my description slightly because I just recalled that I should maintain the original ordering of the `List<MyObject>`, therefore my original solution would have been incorrect anyway since I was doing the sort.  Because of this, I shall continue to follow the path of assistance offered and use a `LinkedHashMap<String, List<Double>>`.  Coming from [Java 6 API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) "This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order)".

Comment: I guess you could probably store them in a `HashMap`, then walk through the array, and either insert into the map, or update the prices as necessary.  Single walk - O(n).  Single access in a `HashMap` is O(1) (... I think?), N times (So, O(n)?).  Something like that I guess....  Then just call `toArray()` if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question you linked seems to be more interested in fuzzy matching (two strings that are "close enough") to one another, but from your question it seems like you're just interested in combining terms that are identical.

If that's the case, you can do this in O(n) time by using a standard `HashMap`.  In particular, your algorithm could work like this:

1. Construct a `HashMap` from `String` to `Double`.
2. For each element in the list:

   1. If the named object doesn't exist in the `HashMap`, insert it with value equal to the price.
   2. If the named object does exist in the `HashMap`, update the value by adding in the value associated with the current object.
3. Iterate across the `HashMap` and for each element, create a new `MyObject` from the key/value pair.

Step 1 takes O(1) time.  Step 2 takes O(n) time, since you do only constant work for each element.  Finally, step 3 takes O(n) time again because you have to visit every element in the `HashMap` exactly once.  Overall this is O(n), which is asymptotically faster than your O(n log n) sorting-based solution.  I also think this is much easier to code up, since you don't need to define a `Comparator` for your type and can just use standard, off-the-shelf Java components.

Hope this helps!

Comment: 25 seconds quicker, and a better explanation :) +1

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it in O(n) by creating a map form `String` to `Double` (or `double`), and walking through the list adding to the double if the `purchase` is already a key, or inserting a new entry if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

pleas try to do it with this way

```
public static ArrayList<EntryData> CompineEntries(EntryData... Entries) {
    ArrayList<EntryData> Compined = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < Entries.length; i++) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < Compined.size(); j++) {
            if (Entries[i].SubAccountID == Compined.get(j).SubAccountID) {
                Compined.get(j).Value += Entries[i].Value;
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            Compined.add(Entries[i]);
        }
    }
    return Compined;
}
```